# How to write the completion for the callable function for Stripe Apple Pay for Native iOS

Tags: ios, google-cloud-functions, cloud, stripe-payments, applepay

I'm following the [Stripe Apple Pay documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay#native). I don't know how to pass the client secret. I'm passing the data to Stripe. The order goes through but I'm not returning the information back to my app to notify the user. The error I'm getting is: Assertion failed: `secret` format does not match expected client secret formatting.

The callable function asks for a String in the success completion but I don't know how to extract it.

The code shown in the documentation is as follows:

```
// Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production!
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_THISISMYSTRIPETESTKEY');

const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
  amount: 1099,
  currency: 'usd',
});
const clientSecret = paymentIntent.client_secret
// Pass the client secret to the client
```

In my index.js for my Cloud Functions, I have a createApplePayCharge function shown below:

```
exports.createApplePayCharge = functions.https.onCall( async (data, context) => {

    const amount = data.total;
    const customerId = data.customer_id;
    const paymentMethodId = data.payment_method_id;
    const idempotency = data.idempotency;
    const description = data.description;

    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        payment_method: paymentMethodId,
        customer: customerId,
        amount: amount,
        description: description,
        currency: 'usd',
        confirm: true,
        payment_method_types: ['card']
    }, {
        idempotencyKey: idempotency
    }).then(object => {
        console.log('Charge Success: ', object.id);
        return paymentIntent.client_secret;
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', ' Unable to create charge: ' + err);
    });

});
```

And in my ProductViewController where I display the Apple Pay Button I have the following function:

```
func applePayContext(_ context: STPApplePayContext, didCreatePaymentMethod paymentMethod: STPPaymentMethod, paymentInformation: PKPayment, completion: @escaping STPIntentClientSecretCompletionBlock) {

    let idempotency = UUID().uuidString.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")
    
    let data : [String: Any] = [
        "total" : 30000.00,
        "customer_id" : Api.userService.user.stripeId,
        "payment_method_id" : paymentMethod.stripeId,
        "idempotency" : idempotency,
        "description" : "Mobile Order - Apple Pay"
    ]
    
    Functions.functions().httpsCallable(Firebase_Functions.applePayCharge).call(data) { (result, error) in
        
        if let error = error {
            completion(error.localizedDescription, error)
            return
        }
        
        completion("Need a String here", nil)
        
    }

}
```

The problem I'm having is that I can not find the String I need for the error and success completions in the code above which is the reason why the app either crashes or does not complete the order process with the following error: Assertion failed: `secret` format does not match expected client secret formatting.

Comment: Would it maybe be `result`? Have you tried printing that out?

Comment: I've tried that but is not printing anything so I figured my cloud function was wrong however the logs show a response.